# Cassandra - Compaction process stuck

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

On one of our server, compaction process is hanging. It's stuck at 80%. It was stuck for last 3 days. And today we did a cluster restart (one host at time). And again it is stuck at same 80%. CPU usages are 100% and there seems no IO issue. We are seeing following WARNING in system.log

```
BatchStatement.java (line 226) Batch of prepared statements for [****, ****] is of size 7557, exceeding specified threshold of 5120 by 2437.
```

I have tried to stop this compaction using nodetool. But this also does not stop.

Can someone please help?

Comment: The message above is purely a warning regarding the batch size being processed by the node. This is a configurable parameter within the cassandra.yaml (e.g. batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb: 64). What do you mean by "compaction process is hanging"? Where did you get that information? What does nodetool compactionstats show (is that were you got the "hanging" information from?)?

Answer (score 0):

How much disk space left ? At least 50% disk space available if you are using STCS compaction strategy.Other reason, On large partition compaction is happening for particular key so you need to delete the data for particular key.